# on click apply class with different css properties

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to apply a class on click to `li` of my `div`.

This is the js I have.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#toggleme').click(function() {
     $(this1).addClass('active_class');
});
});
```

Now when I click at the cart, I want to change that cart image.

I am trying to do that via the css by applying the class `background-image:url("");` property. But for some reason I am not able to get it working.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1jc4a9ot/3/)
Please help.

Comment: Try to use only icons and not images. It is a better practice. http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: well, the images are of different colors and attributes so can't use icons or something.

Comment: If you change the color attribute it will change the icon color too. You can make all you text effects in css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JS code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var img=0;
    $('#toggleme').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active_class');
        if(img==0){
            $(this).find("img").attr("src", 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/simple-red-glossy-icons-business/086707-simple-red-glossy-icon-business-cart5.png');
             img=1;
        }else{
            $(this).find("img").attr("src", 'http://www.daru-koi.com/images/winkelwagen.png');
            img=0;
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1jc4a9ot/10/)

Also note that the icon in your code is due to the `img` tag source and not the CSS. Therefore overwriting using CSS will not help.

The above code switches the source everytime you click.

Comment: my class `activeclass` isn't getting applied with your code. I am doing other css property as well so need to append properties of `activeclass` as well.

If you see, I am changing the color in `activeclass`

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggleme').click(function() {
         $('.menu').toggle("slide");
         $(this).toggleClass('active_class');

                 if(img==0){
            $(this).find("img").attr("src", '/assets/cartlogo.png');
             img=1;
        }else{
            $(this).find("img").attr("src", '/assets/cart1logo.jpeg');
            img=0;
        }
    });
});`


Doesn't really work

Comment: Can you check the console to see if there are any errors?

Answer (score 1):

See [the cascade](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/cascade.html#cascade).

> count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector

You have two background image rules applying to the element:

```
.active_class {
   background-image : url("http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/simple-red-glossy-icons-business/086707-simple-red-glossy-icon-business-cart5.png");
}
```

and

```
style="background-image:none"
```

The style attribute one is more specific and "wins".

Avoid style attributes. Define the default styling in the stylesheet. (Or just remove it entirely since `none` is the default in the browser stylesheet).

Comment: shouldn't that get replaced when I do the click? I am not sure how `style="background-image:none"` this thing is getting applied

Comment: "shouldn't that get replaced when I do the click?" — No. Your JS doesn't touch the style attribute.

Comment: "I am not sure how style="background-image:none" this thing is getting applied" — It is hardcoded into the HTML you put in your live example.

Comment: Get it, completely. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery is working correctly in that it is toggling the active_class when clicked.  You can use developer tools (in Chrome or IE, press F12) to verify.

The problem is your jQuery targets the `<li>` element, but you have an `<img />` element within it that is not affected by jQuery in any way.

You need to have the default cart image displayed as a background in CSS and use the jQuery to toggle between it and a different image.